# SQL pivot for kohorts

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a table for customers activity for last 5 months. The example looks like this:

| month | id_client | month_number | activity |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-10-01 | 1234 | 1 | NULL |
| 2023-11-01 | 1234 | 2 | NULL |
| 2023-12-01 | 1234 | 3 | 1 |
| 2024-01-01 | 1234 | 4 | 0 |
| 2024-02-01 | 1234 | 5 | 0 |

Where 1=active, 0=not active, NULL=not active, because he didn't register yet (I want to keep these NULLS)

What I want to achive is:

| month | id_client | month_number_1 | month_number_2 | month_number_3 | month_number_4 month_number_5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-10-01 | 1234 | NULL | NULL | 1 | 0 |
| 2023-11-01 | 1234 | NULL | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 2023-12-01 | 1234 | 1 | 0 | 0 | NULL |
| 2024-01-01 | 1234 | 0 | 0 | NULL | NULL |
| 2024-02-01 | 1234 | 0 | NULL | NULL | NULL |

I think I should use some kind of pivot, but I don't know how.

Answer (score 0):

With **pivot** data is transform from rows into columns. However, here the task is that the data from future rows is displayed in extra columns. This is performed with **window** functions.

I changed the `null` to `-1`, so that it is easier to see, how the SQL query reacts on missing entries.

Here the calculated `yyyymm` column is used to find the next month, maybe the column `month_number` can be used instead.

```sql
WITH sample as (Select month, 1234 id_client, offset+1 as month_number, 
case offset  when 2 then 1 when 3 then 0 when 4 then 0 else null end as activity 
from 
unnest(generate_date_array(date"2023-10-01", date"2024-02-01",interval 1 month)) as month with offset 
),
tbl1 as  (
Select * except(activity),
ifnull(activity,-1) as activity, # replace null entries with -1
extract(year from month)*12 +  extract(month from month) as yyyymm, # we need to access the next month by a value
from sample
)

select *,
any_value(activity) over win1 as activity_after_1month,
any_value(activity) over win2 as activity_after_2month,
any_value(activity) over win3 as activity_after_3month,
any_value(activity) over win4 as activity_after_4month,
any_value(activity) over win5 as activity_after_5month,

from tbl1
window
win1 as (partition by id_client order by yyyymm range between 1 following and 1 following),
win2 as (partition by id_client order by yyyymm range between 2 following and 2 following),
win3 as (partition by id_client order by yyyymm range between 3 following and 3 following),
win4 as (partition by id_client order by yyyymm range between 4 following and 4 following),
win5 as (partition by id_client order by yyyymm range between 5 following and 5 following)
```